# Extending Iterator for dynamic dispatch

Tags: rust, iterator, dynamic-dispatch

I want to extend the Iterator trait with some convenience function. For example

```rust
trait BetterIterator: Iterator { 
    fn skip_bad(&mut self); 
}
```

This can be achieved like this:

```rust
struct Iter {}

impl Iterator for Iter {
    type Item = ();
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<()> { None }
}


impl BetterIterator for Iter {
    fn skip_bad(&mut self) {}
}

fn make_iter() -> Box<dyn BetterIterator<Item=()>> {
    Box::new( Iter {} )
}

fn main() 
{
    let mut iter = make_iter();
    iter.skip_bad();
    for _item in iter {
        // ...
    }
}
```

What is unusual, here, is the dynamic dispatch in `make_iter`.

Now, it would be much nicer if `skip_bad` could be chained, e.g.

```rust
    for _item in make_iter().skip_bad() {
        // ...
    }
```

That means `BetterIterator` becomes

```
trait BetterIterator: Iterator { 
    fn skip_bad(&mut self) -> &mut Self; 
}

impl BetterIterator for Iter {
    fn skip_bad(&mut self) -> &mut Self { self }
}
```

But then the compiler complains "the trait `BetterIterator` cannot be made into an object".

Is it correct that the violated rule in [Object Safety](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety) is "Dispatchable functions require: ...Be a method that does not use Self except in the type of the receiver."?

There is no way out of this, is there?

Comment: Maybe write a trait with a blanket impl for any `BetterIterator` that has the method returning `&mut Self`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If dynamic dispatch is your goal you can return a mutable reference to a `dyn BetterIterator` instead.

```rust
trait BetterIterator: Iterator {
    fn skip_bad(&mut self) -> &mut dyn BetterIterator<Item = Self::Item>;
}

impl BetterIterator for Iter {
    fn skip_bad(&mut self) -> &mut dyn BetterIterator<Item = Self::Item> { self }
}
```